# Permission denied. Rails could not complete the installation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux

I tried to install Ruby on Rails in my user account. Atraves user terminal, do the following.

1. I find that the minimum requirements are met
2. I write the command line to install Rails (poor man).
3. I get the following error message at the beginning of the installation process:

   ```
   Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
   Checking requirements for debian.
   Installing requirements for debian

   user password required for /usr/bin/env PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:usr/local   /games:/usr/games:/home/user/.rvm/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/sbin apt-get --quiet --yes update:

   Updating system.
   Error running requirements_debian_update_system ruby-2.0.0-p247, please read /home/user.rvm/log/1380100570_ruby-2.0.0-p247/update_system.log
   Requirements installation failed with status: 1.
   ```

Comment: What does /home/user.rvm/log/1380100570_ruby-2.0.0-p247/update_system.log tell you?

Comment: "`:usr/local   /games`" doesn't make sense. Please edit your question and put in the text, being careful to paste it without any line wrapping. As is, it appears you have a space in your path which would confuse the system.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. I have not much experience with ruby, (much less with linux), so when something does not work, I can not just stare at the screen without doing anything. This is one of those moments.
Yesterday afternoon the Rails I knew a number of problems loading the runtime execjs requesting. I have not solved, but I thought that maybe jaba loading the runtime could fix it. I'm on it. I'll open another thread where monitor the results I get, if anyone wants to join new thread:
Starting the rails, sqlite3 Error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by reinstalling ruby separately with the version I wanted to use.
Then install rails via `gem install rails-v`
then clear the gem that made ​​reference to the error and rerun `bundle install` . Then select the version I wanted to use installing ruby rvm `rvm use default -v`

Answer (score 2):

Maybe your problem is related with sudoers file. 
try edit this file:

```
vim /etc/sudoers
```

in this file should be your user name with permissions. For example:

```
your_user_name    ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

try to add if it don't exists:)